# Index big document content into Bonsai synchronous fashion

Tags: elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I have implemented the Bonsai document indexing using Ruby on Rails and deployed on Heroku. when I loop through all the documents with document content indexing then I get http 504 error for some requests.

I am using elasticsearch-api gem with rails 4.2.

```
    documents.each do |document|
        client.update(
          index: 'sample_index_name', type: 'document', id: document.id.to_s, body: {doc: {doc_content: '..base64 encoded content..'}})
    end
```